# Evidence for/against Lexical integrity principle

Tags: syntax, morphosyntax, phrase-structure, dependency-grammar

Some (mostly lexicalist) theories of syntax assume that there's a 1-to-1 relationship between the words in a sentence and the nodes in its syntax tree. It seems pretty obvious to me. Is there empirical evidence against this principle?

Comment: There can't be empirical evidence against your principle, because it's not an empirical principle.

Comment: Hey Pedro, who are you? Where are you? You might think about identifying yourself. That would encourage people like me to answer your questions.

Comment: I share Tim Osborne's concern. Since February 19th you've asked [13 questions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/8145/pedro?tab=questions&sort=activity), of which 9 are answered - all by [Atamiri](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/atamiri). Often competing answers received more votes than the accepted answer provided by Atamiri. See also this [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11815/dependencies-in-case-phrases) on Japanese, which went to Atamiri again (without any Japanese data). The question then is "**Are you a sockpuppet of Atamiri?**"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, and for the same reason there is evidence against the 'no tampering' computational principle of current Merge-based minimalist syntax: sublexical elements (typically 'features', [attribute: value] pairs) must be visible to computational operations and result affected by them (e.g., unvalued [A:v] pairs get valued as a result of syntactic operations),and, conversely, sublexical [A: v] features trigger/block syntactic operations. Also, at the semantic level, 'coercion' modifies the internal features of lexical items as they get constructed with neighbouring lexical items, and not only 'locally' (as a consequence of direct 'external Merge' between two lexical units L1 and L2), but also non-locally, as when a noun or verb undergo 'meaning coercion' resulting from NPs or VPs being subsequently constructed with e.g. certain adverbials. Under a strict view of lexical integrity, none of that should occur. Needless to say, parallel reasoning applies to the 'phonological' component of the grammar to the extent sub-lexical phonological features can be affected by comparable features of neighbouring lexical items, obvious cases being 'sandhi' and vowel harmony phenomena. Finally, of course 'lexical integrity' cannot be a principle of any grammar in which at some point (say 'Spell Out', in standard minimalist grammar) the computation branches into two sub-computations, one sending 'meaning'-related information towards the 'conceptual-intentional interface' and the other sending 'sound'-related information towards the 'articulatory-perceptual' one. The latter argument, of course, applies only to theories like Chomsky's minimalist grammar, but the preceeding ones, terminological issues aside, are more generally applicable to all theories of grammar I am aware of to the extent they are explicit as to the computations they presuppose.